# Problems with loading flash files into WebView

Tags: android, flash, webview

I'm trying to load a simple swf into an embebed WebView.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    WebView wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web);
    WebSettings settings = wv.getSettings();
    settings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/example.swf");

}
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <WebView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:id="@+id/web"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I don't see anything wrong in this code... but still my web view shows black

By Checking the LogChat I have found this error:

```
11-30 12:46:32.170: E/libEGL(13839): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
```

By is that? How can I solve it?

I am using this swf: http://www.tizag.com/pics/example.swf

I am working with a Motorola Xoom - Android 3.1.

Could anyone helpme with this?

Comment: Does the device have flash installed?

Comment: Yes, The thing is that if I load http://www.tizag.com/pics/example.swf from the device browser it works fine, but from my webView it didn't ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just find my own answer!!!! You should activate the attribute android:hardwareAccelerated in your aplication in your manifest like so:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true" >
```